# La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto. C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Primero que nada perdón por tantas preguntas que para muchos de ustedes deben de ser cosas insignificantes me imagino, (errores de aprendiz digamos)
El tema es así: Tengo propiedades, cada propiedad tiene rangos de fechas (fecha inicio y fecha fin) hice lo siguiente de 2 formas distintas para probar si por ahí le había errado en algo y me saltó el siguiente error: "La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto"

A continuación pongo el código para que puedan ver.
En el mapper de propiedades lo hice así.

```
 public List<Propiedad> obtenerRangosPorIdPropiedad(int xIdPropiedad)
        {
            List<Propiedad> listaPropiedades= new List<Propiedad>();
            var param = new List<SqlParameter>();
            var idPropiedad = new SqlParameter();
            idPropiedad .ParameterName = "@idPropiedad ";
            idPropiedad .Value = xIdPropiedad;
            param.Add(idPropiedad );
            var conn = abrirConexion();
            var r = @select("SELECT * FROM Propiedad p  JOIN Rango r ON r.idPropiedad  = a.idPropiedad WHERE idPropiedad= @idPropiedad", CommandType.Text, param, conn, null);
            while(r.Read())
            {
                listaPropiedades.Add(CargarPropiedad(r));
            }
            cerrarConexion(conn);
            return listaPropiedades;
        }
```

En la parte de servicios lo hice de esta otra forma:

```
public List<Rango> obtenerRangosDePropiedades(int xIdPropiedad)
        {
            List<Rango> listaRangos = obtenerTodosLosRangos();
            List<Rango> rangosFiltrados = new List<Rango>();
            foreach(var objR in listaRangos)
            {
                if(objR.propiedad.idPropiedad == xIdPropiedad)
                {
                    rangosFiltrados.Add(objR);
                }
            }
            return rangosFiltrados;
        }
```

Y acá es en donde me tira el error, en el codebehind hago lo siguiente:

En el load llamo a un método que hace esto

```
private void cargarRangos()
        {
            lstRangos.DataSource = new GestoraRango().obtenerRangosDePropiedades(Convert.ToInt32(lstPropiedades.SelectedValue)); //En esta línea me tira ese error.
            lstRangos.DataTextField = "datos";
            lstRangos.DataValueField = "idRango";
            lstRangos.DataBind();
        }
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: En el método "obtenerRangosPorIdPropiedad" usa la variable `param` como un string a la instrucción SQL que "por cierto" no parece completa.
Encierre su código en un bloque try/catch. Para mí, el error está al concatenar la consulta SQL con la variable "param" cuando ésta es de tipo SqlParameter.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, voy a probar con lo de try/catch, en cuanto a lo de param no creo que sea eso porque tengo varios métodos hechos de esa forma y sin embargo funcionan, además lo implementé de otra forma y me tira el mismo error, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

El problema esta dentro del metodo `CargarPropiedad()` ya que es en este conde conviertes los campos del datareader a propiedades de la entidad.

Valida con un breakpoint que valor recibes en los campos de fecha porque esta claro que alguno no es valido.

Tambien puedes usar el DateTime.TryParse() para convertir a fecha pero sin tener la exception si esta es invalida

```
DateTime fecha;
if(DateTime.TryParse(r["nombrecampo"].ToString(), out fecha))
{
   entidad.PropFecha = fecha;
}
```

des esta forma si el valor que recibes no es valido no tendras un error

Comment: Con un breakpoint en el método CargarRango() recibo null, las fechas se las paso mediante calendar con selecteddate, ¿puede ser que en la base de datos el tipo esté solo como "Date" y en Visual está en "DateTime"?

Comment: en realidad apuntaba a un brekpoint dentro de CargarRango() entonces poder ir paso a paso evaluando como se asignan los valores de las propiedades cuando recuperas del datareader. Si el campo esta como date entonces deberia tener una fecha en formato correcto por el tipo de error es una conversion de un valor invalido, puede que sea alguna cadena que al convertirla a numero falle

Comment: Usé el breakpoint en el método cargarRangos() ` private void cargarRangos()
        {

            //lstRangos.DataSource = new GestoraRango().obtenerTodosLosRangos();
            lstRangos.DataSource = new GestoraRango().obtenerRangosDeAlojamientos(Convert.ToInt32(lstPropiedades.SelectedValue));
            lstRangos.DataTextField = "datos";
            lstRangos.DataValueField = "idRango";
            lstRangos.DataBind();
        }` me da el error en la línea "lstRangos.DataSource...etc, si cambio el método por por uno que se llama "ObtenerTodosLosRangos() no da error.

Answer (score 0):

En el método `cargarRangos()` aparece la siguiente línea:

```
lstRangos.DataSource = new GestoraRango().obtenerRangosDePropiedades(Convert.ToInt32(lstPropiedades.SelectedValue)); //En esta línea me tira ese error.
```

Antes de asignar la fuente de datos a `lstRangos`, debe validar que `lstPropiedades` NO sea NULL y que además tenga datos.

Es posible que `lstPropiedades.SelectedValue` sea NULL o un valor que no pueda convertirse a `Int32`.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, lstPropiedades tiene propiedades cargadas si, está así:   protected void `lstPropiedades_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(lstPropiedades.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                var obt = new GestoraPropiedades().obtenerPropiedadesPorId(Convert.ToInt32(lstPropiedades.SelectedValue)); `

Comment: @Ccccccccc: edita tu pregunta con el código fuente. Los comentarios fueron diseñados para pedir clarificaciones, dejar criticismo constructivo, o agregar información adicional.